# How to get Max value column header and Row header?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please see the screenshot. I want header of that column which have maximum value. I also want header of that row.

[image]

Comment: I don't know why people down voting the post? Can anyone explain why you down voting the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This formula for Max value column header:

```
=INDEX($B$7:$F$7,MAX(IF($B$8:$F$10=MAX($B$8:$F$10),COLUMN($B$8:$F$10))-COLUMN($B$7)+1))
```

Use This formula for Max value row header:

```
=INDEX($B$7:$B$10,MAX(IF($B$8:$F$10=MAX($B$8:$F$10),ROW($B$8:$F$10)-ROW($B$7)+1)))
```

Both are array formula, so press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` after finishing entering formula.

[image]